# Is there any risk in receiving ETH in a pre-hard fork account having equal amounts of ETH and ETC?

Tags: ether, security, accounts, hardforks, replay-attack

As written in the title, I am wondering if doing this would be safe, or if there's anything else I should be aware about. I want to buy ETH via Kraken and send it to that account.

I've been reading on the implications of the hard fork and I'm having some trouble making sense of it all, and would like to be safe before doing anything.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no risk in receiving ETH to an account.  The account will end up with a higher ETH balance than ETC balance.

Spending from the account is where one needs to be very careful of replay attacks.  For example, even though the account has a smaller ETC balance, care needs to be taken against replays because anyone can fill up the account's ETC balance (so that it equals the ETH balance) to make replays possible.

Comment: Sorry, hitting enter submitted that comment instead of adding a line, I have one more question if you don't mind, would a replay attack only imply a risk if I sent ETH to an address that I don't own? This is my current understanding, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you only send ETH to accounts that you have the private keys for, then you are always in control of funds, despite the nuisance/confusion that replays can try to cause.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR always use different address for ETH than you use for ETC.

If you have an address that contains both ETH and ETC funds, generally that's bad, and you should avoid it.

What happens is you transfer ETH from that account to some other account - and then replay attacks execute the exact same transaction on the ETC chain, so the same amount of ETC transfers to the same account.  I confirmed this happened to me when transferring from one of my own accounts to another of my own accounts.

Basically it makes it so it's impossible for you to transfer ETH without also transferring ETC to the same place.  This is obviously not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation. I'll soon split the ETH and ETC in my accounts once I've figured out what wallet/exchange to use. Until then, the ETH bought via Kraken will be sent to a newly created account.